# when I have a popup appear on top of my page, then use the scroll keys, the page scrolls, but not the popup

Tags: jquery, css, focus

I have a regular php web page. When you click a certain element, a popup appears with more content. The thing is, when the popup appears, if the user scrolls, I want the popup content to scroll. Instead, when the user scrolls, the web page under the popup scrolls. I've tried `.focus()`, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it only works on form widgets. Can anyone suggest a solution?

html:

```
<div class="anecdote-thumb" id="anecdote-BOA">
<img src="img/story/web-21090319MMSbuildings3.jpg">
<p class="anecdote-link-p"><strong><a class="anecdote-link" href="#"  onclick="return false;" id="show-BOA">Details</a></strong></p>
</div>

<!------------------ POPUP ---------------------------------->  
<div class="popup" id="popup-BOA">
<div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div>
<!-- content here -->
<p class="text-close text-center">Close</p>
</div>  
<!------------------ END POPUP ------------>
```

css:

```
.popup {
    width: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    height:80%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index:99;
    display:none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.anecdote-link').on('click', function(){
        $('.mask').fadeIn();
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == "show-BOA" ) {
            $('#popup-BOA').fadeIn();
        }
});
```

Comment: The scrolling element will be in effect where the mouse is shown. So if it's not over the popup, it will scroll the page, and vice versa. So unless you're talking about the user using the keyboard to scroll, in which focus will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable overflow body of the page, e.g. with such code when calling the popup function:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Remember to restore - you can add this code on close:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

Comment: It's not the overflow I want to control. I want the focus to be on the popup that's on top of the page. I want the popup to scroll when you start scrolling/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/15pyuste/ <- Look at this jsfiddle. I see no scrolling problem here. I added your code here. Since your scrollbar in the pop-up window does not work, I recommended turning off the overflow of what is under it - body. With the help of this page' overflow underneath it will not work while the pop-up window is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you can't scroll, because your content is not overflowing anything. I made the the content to be a little more than the height viewport, and it seems to be scrolling just fine in the middle popup, take a look at this quick demo:

```js
$('.anecdote-link').on('click', function(){
        $('.mask').fadeIn();
        if ( $(this).attr('id') == "show-BOA" ) {
            $('#popup-BOA').fadeIn();
        }
});
```

```css
body{
  height:140vh;
}

.popup {
    width: 60%;
    position: fixed;
    height:80%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index:99;
    display:none;

    height: 120vh;
}  

.close{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="anecdote-thumb" id="anecdote-BOA">
        <img src="img/story/web-21090319MMSbuildings3.jpg">
        <p class="anecdote-link-p"><strong><a class="anecdote-link" href="#"  onclick="return false;" id="show-BOA">Details</a></strong></p>
        </div>
        
        <!------------------ POPUP ---------------------------------->  
        <div class="popup" id="popup-BOA">
        <div class="close"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></div>
        <!-- content here -->
        <p class="text-close text-center">Close</p>
        </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me in your demo. Again, only the bottom element scrolls, not the popup. Maybe this is a "feature" of Chrome?

Comment: What, that's strange, for me, it works completely fine in chrome, the popup scrolls but not the body element.